# Icon same color as Buttons

Tags: website-design, buttons, design-patterns, icons

This is a simple website demo, with 2 buttons, a icon, and a main display with text information.

I like the uniform look of this, color wise. But, I am concerned I am breaking a rule or causing confusion having the `people are viewing this site` icon the same look as the buttons above. Is this ok for user experience?

[image]

Comment: When I look at it, "1" looks like a button I would click.  Maybe it would show me some type of stats or history or a list of who is there and logged in, or where the people "on" the site have connected from (maybe a map of the globe with hotspots)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not breaking the rule if like what Baronz said, its a button that links to another page. However if its just for display purpose or graphical cue then its confusing to the user.

If you made the icon to look exactly like a button in terms of shape, size and color (for your case even the dropshadow effect), then user will perceive that they behave the same way. At first glance without reading your description, I thought so too it is a button.

A few suggestions, you might want to remove the drop shadow or change the color of the icon to differentiate it from clickable elements. Perhaps you could try using gray color for the icon.

Comment: I will change the icon color. Also, is the `people are viewing` text ok free standing like that or should it have be on a icon also?

Comment: Either 1) inside the icon, at a glance you know the "1" is referring to people viewing 2) Move the text closer to the icon and separate it from other text so that they are grouped together 3) Alternatively place the text beside the icon.

Comment: With 3) do you mean on the left or right of the icon rather than below? For 2) I can move the text closer, but I don't want it so close I ruin the shadow effect. Thanks!

Comment: You can put it on the right if you have space. np.